# How do I compare arbitrarily nested numpy ndarrays?

Tags: python, numpy

Leaving aside if this is a good idea or not, how can I compare two nested arrays in numpy?

```
>>> a
array([[array([0, 0]), array([0, 1])],
       [array([1, 0]), array([1, 1])]], dtype=object)

>>> b
array([[array([0, 0]), array([0, 1])],
       [array([1, 0]), array([1, 1])]], dtype=object)

>>> np.array_equal(a, b)
False

>>> np.equal(a, b, dtype=object)
array([[array([ True,  True]), array([ True,  True])],
       [array([ True,  True]), array([ True,  True])]], dtype=object)
   
>>> np.equal(a, b, dtype=object).all()
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: working with nested object arrays could be seen as a numpy nonsense. Do you have a particular reason not to use lists or a non-object nd-array?

Comment: Yes, I do indeed have very specific reasons for doing it like this -- I am building an APL compiler atop numpy, and I need to be able to store potentially different-shaped elements (although in this example, each element is of the same shape).

Comment: It's been years since I used APL, but I don't recall working with the equivalent of object dtype arrays.

Comment: I dont know wether I'm copying something wrong, but to me both `array_equal` and `equal().all()`  gives True. (numpy version '1.24.2')

Comment: Make your example ragged so people don't mistakenly created n-d arrays.

Comment: or make the example copy-pasteable so it produces a (2,2) array, not a (2,2,2)

Comment: Math on object dtype arrays is messy.  Sometimes it works, as in `a-b`.  You found that `equal` works, provided you specify dtype.   The operation has to iterate on the objects, applying a relevant operator to each.  Speed is comparable to list comprehensions.  But often this kind of recursion doesn't work.  `np.sin` is an example.

Comment: Recent APLs allow for nested arrays; that is the model is boxed. An array is a n-d array with a shape, but each elemen is a boxed cell that can contain anything. Emulating this in numpy is annoyingly tricky.

Comment: See e.g. https://tryapl.org/?clear=&q=2%202%E2%8D%B4(1%202)3(4%205)6&run=